# Retrofit server response is getting 307 in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Step1:
    Need to give input to server.as below image
    [image]

```
step2:
get response from server ,as below image.

 ![enter image description here][2]

step3:
MainActivity.java

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.URL_BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);


    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    try {
        JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
        paramObject.put("merchant_id", "aaaaa");
        paramObject.put("secret_key", "bbbbb");

        Call<RequestBody> userCall = apiInterface.getUser(paramObject.toString());
        userCall.enqueue(this);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, Response<RequestBody> response) {
    Log.d("TEST","TEST--onResponse1---"+call);
    Log.d("TEST","TEST--onResponse2---"+response);

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.d("TEST","TEST--onFailure1--"+call);
    Log.d("TEST","TEST--onFailure1--"+t);
}
========================================================
 step4:  ApiInterface.hava

public interface ApiInterface {

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<RequestBody> getUser(@Body String body);
 }
```

> Log is going to "onResponse.code()" is getting 307" but i count able
>   to get proper data.
>       I am new to Retrofit service.Can please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send `String` to Retrofit without using some other library.

Since you're using Gson already. Create a class that Gson can serialize.

```
class Credentials {
    @SerializedName("merchant_id")
    public String merchantId;

    @SerializedName("secret_key")
    public String secretKey;
}
```

Interface method. @Notice the input type.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<RequestBody> getUser(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

`307` is `Temporary Redirect` - and you might have to follow that redirect.

Which means, that you need to configure the `OkHttpClient` to do so:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .followSslRedirects(true)
   .followRedirects(true)
   .build();
```

and then set it as the client for `retrofit2`:

```
retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .build();
```